# Internationalization with multiple subdomains

Tags: google-chrome-extension, internationalization, locale, google-chrome-app

I am releasing multiple languages for my app in Chrome App Store.

I am trying to release my app so that it links Chrome App Story language version to our subdomains as per language.

Example:

```
//in manifest.json:
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "default_locale": "en",

//in _locales/en/messages.json:
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "My App",
    "description": "The title of the application, displayed in the web store."
  },
  "appDesc": {
    "message": "This app does something awesome.", 
    "description":"The description of the application, displayed in the web store."
  }

  >>>> THIS LANGUAGE SHOULD USE URL - EN.MYDOMAIN.COM

}

//in _locales/de/messages.json:
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "My Application German"
  },
  "appDesc": {
    "message": "This application does something brilliant in German."
  }

  >>>> THIS LANGUAGE SHOULD USE URL - DE.MYDOMAIN.COM

}
```

---

All support much appreciated. How can I get Chrome App Store to redirect to correct locale subdomain url as per language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "should use URL" mean? Are you a hosted app or packaged app? If you mean hosted app, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85034, and the resulting code change, an example of which is here: https://codereview.chromium.org/9421010/diff/6001/chrome/test/data/extensions/manifest_tests/launch_local_path_localized.json

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "version": "1",
   "default_locale": "en",
   "app": {
     "launch": {
       "local_path": "__MSG_local_launch_path__"
     }
   }
}
```